# Jquery / Ajax update Span or Div by ID without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

SO I have the following code:

```
<span class='numberofthings' id='123456'> Things: ".$things."</span>
```

And the following JS / Ajax code:

```
function click(obj) {

    $.ajax({
        var id = 123456
            ..code...
        success: function() {
            ...Have it reload the Span above by using the ID
        }
    });
}
```

I have seen ways of updating a div using :

```
$("#divId").load(location.href + " #divId>*", "");
```

but I tried to apply it to my situation and it didn't work. Basically, the reason I need the span to update is because I have other code that changes the value of $things

Comment: `Have it reload the Span above by using the ID` what does this mean?

Comment: Do you want to update the span text?

Comment: Yes .. or the HTML either will work

Comment: Using the term "reload" will confuse a lot of people, a better term is "update"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the new value of things from the `success` callback and update the `<span id="123456">` with `.html()`

```
function click(obj) {    
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function() {
            var new_things = ''; // Here is where you fetch new data from the response.
            $('#123456').html("Things: " + new_things);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. Also let's say that the ID I needed to update the html for, instead of being #123456, was a variable, say the variable was named "thingsvariable". How could I fix this so it works?

var thingsvariable = "'#foranexample'";
$(thingsvariable).html("Things:" + new_things);

Comment: Yes. The code in the comment will do what you want.

Comment: It doesn't though , I just double checked

Comment: Does the code work if you write `$("#foranexample").html("Things:" + new_things);` instead of `var thingsvariable = "'#foranexample'"; $(thingsvariable).html("Things:" + new_things);`?

Comment: Okay, thank you for taking the time to reply and help me. I was doing "'#foranexample'" instead of "#foranexample" .. but it's sorted now, thanks again <3